# python: How to graph Sankey graph in a dash app

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, visualization, plotly-dash

I have been trying to create a Sankey graph on a dash application using the [plotly tutorial](https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/#sankey-diagram-in-dash), but I have had  no sucess in achieving that. I have been stuck with the below error `dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback ..my_bee_map.figure.. is a multi-output.` I can figure out how to fix that.

my end objective is to see the flow of Labels and years with values `>=0.75`. what that means is that when I choose a label e.g `cs.AI`, I want to see the flow of `labels`, `years` with   `>=0.75` values correlated to the label `cs.AI`
[image]

Here is my dash app and the values for the plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px  # (version 4.7.0 or higher)
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import numpy as np 
from dash import Dash # pip install dash (version 2.0.0 or higher)

app = Dash(__name__)

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H1("Web Application Dashboards with Dash", style={'text-align': 'center'}),

    dcc.Dropdown(id="slct_label",
                  options=[{'label': x, 'value': x} for x in
                              sorted(df["Label1"].unique())],
                 multi=False,
                 value="cs.AI",
                 style={'width': "30%"}
                 ),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Dropdown(id="slct_value",
                  options=[{'label': x, 'value': x} for x in
                              sorted(df[df["value"] >= 0.75]["value"].unique())],
                 multi=False,
                 value=0.75,
                 style={'width': "40%"},
                 placeholder="Select threshold"
                 ),
                 
    # html.Div(id='output_container', children=[]),
    html.Br(),

    dcc.Graph(id='my_bee_map', figure={})

])

# Callback - app interactivity section------------------------------------
@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='output_container', component_property='children'),
     Output(component_id='my_bee_map', component_property='figure')],
    [Input(component_id='slct_label', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='slct_value', component_property='value')]
)

def update_graph(slct_label, slct_value):
    # print(slct_label,slct_value)
    # print(type(slct_label), type(slct_value))

    container = "The year chosen by user was: {}".format(slct_label)

    dff = df.copy()
    # if slct_label:
    dff = df[df['Label1'] != slct_label]
    
    label = list(dff['Label1'].unique())
    source = np.repeat(np.arange(0, 5), 18).tolist()
    Value = list(dff['value'])
    target = list(dff['Label1'])
    color = np.repeat(np.array(['#a6cee3','#fdbf6f','#fb9a99','#e3a6ce','#a6e3da'],dtype=object), 18).tolist()
    link = dict(source=source,target=target,value=Value,color=color)
    
    node = dict(label=label,pad=35,thickness=15)
    data = go.Sankey(link=link,node=node)
    
    #graph the Sankey
    fig = go.Figure(data)
    fig.update_layout(
        hovermode= 'x',
        title = 'Migration from 1990 to 1992',
        font=dict(size=10,color='white'),
        paper_bgcolor='#51504f')
    
    return fig, container

  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

my data

```
    Label1  value   year
0   cs.AI   1.00    1990
1   cs.AI   0.20    1990
2   cs.AI   0.85    1990
3   cs.AI   0.99    1990
4   cs.AI   0.19    1990
5   cs.AI   0.87    1990
6   cs.CC   0.19    1990
7   cs.CC   1.00    1990
8   cs.CC   0.34    1990
9   cs.CC   0.50    1990
10  cs.CC   0.09    1990
11  cs.CC   0.67    1990
12  cs.CE   0.94    1990
13  cs.CE   0.63    1990
14  cs.CE   1.00    1990
15  cs.CE   0.61    1990
16  cs.CE   0.82    1990
17  cs.CE   0.17    1990
18  cs.CG   0.74    1990
19  cs.CG   0.95    1990
20  cs.CG   0.53    1990
21  cs.CG   1.00    1990
22  cs.CG   0.43    1990
23  cs.CG   0.10    1990
24  cs.CL   0.31    1990
25  cs.CL   0.27    1990
26  cs.CL   0.91    1990
27  cs.CL   0.21    1990
28  cs.CL   1.00    1990
29  cs.CL   0.12    1990
30  cs.CR   0.31    1990
31  cs.CR   0.18    1990
32  cs.CR   0.76    1990
33  cs.CR   0.35    1990
34  cs.CR   0.67    1990
35  cs.CR   1.00    1990
36  cs.AI   1.00    1991
37  cs.AI   0.55    1991
38  cs.AI   0.82    1991
39  cs.AI   0.05    1991
40  cs.AI   0.17    1991
41  cs.AI   0.83    1991
42  cs.CC   0.52    1991
43  cs.CC   1.00    1991
44  cs.CC   0.64    1991
45  cs.CC   1.00    1991
46  cs.CC   0.80    1991
47  cs.CC   0.21    1991
48  cs.CE   0.10    1991
49  cs.CE   0.58    1991
50  cs.CE   1.00    1991
51  cs.CE   0.01    1991
52  cs.CE   0.77    1991
53  cs.CE   0.19    1991
54  cs.CG   0.08    1991
55  cs.CG   0.21    1991
56  cs.CG   0.63    1991
57  cs.CG   1.00    1991
58  cs.CG   0.34    1991
59  cs.CG   0.60    1991
60  cs.CL   0.91    1991
61  cs.CL   0.33    1991
62  cs.CL   0.60    1991
63  cs.CL   0.57    1991
64  cs.CL   1.00    1991
65  cs.CL   0.37    1991
66  cs.CR   1.00    1991
67  cs.CR   0.28    1991
68  cs.CR   0.92    1991
69  cs.CR   0.47    1991
70  cs.CR   0.53    1991
71  cs.CR   1.00    1991
72  cs.AI   1.00    1992
73  cs.AI   0.79    1992
74  cs.AI   0.86    1992
75  cs.AI   0.30    1992
76  cs.AI   0.27    1992
77  cs.AI   0.91    1992
78  cs.CC   0.06    1992
79  cs.CC   1.00    1992
80  cs.CC   0.72    1992
81  cs.CC   0.44    1992
82  cs.CC   0.31    1992
83  cs.CC   0.75    1992
84  cs.CE   0.40    1992
85  cs.CE   0.07    1992
86  cs.CE   1.00    1992
87  cs.CE   0.88    1992
88  cs.CE   0.79    1992
89  cs.CE   0.03    1992
90  cs.CG   0.74    1992
91  cs.CG   0.91    1992
92  cs.CG   1.00    1992
93  cs.CG   1.00    1992
94  cs.CG   0.68    1992
95  cs.CG   0.22    1992
96  cs.CL   0.42    1992
97  cs.CL   0.03    1992
98  cs.CL   0.95    1992
99  cs.CL   0.17    1992
100 cs.CL   1.00    1992
101 cs.CL   0.28    1992
102 cs.CR   0.04    1992
103 cs.CR   0.30    1992
104 cs.CR   0.26    1992
105 cs.CR   0.80    1992
106 cs.CR   0.90    1992
107 cs.CR   1.00    1992
```

Answer (score 0):

what you put after "return" statement has to be placed in the same order as in callbacks. It means that in your code, the return should be: "return container, fig" instead of "return fig, container".
If it does not work, try to separate callback with one output sankey figure only (and do not use square bracket outside Output statement when you have only one output). You can make another callback for container output.